# how is i18n going to fit in react-redux and react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

How should I access the custom props from Provider (react-redux), or is it not possible? For example, I specify i18n as provider's props and hoping that it'll get passed down

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import i18n from './i18n';

import App from '../app';
import Login from '../pages/login';

console.log(i18n.t('greeting')); // good morning

const Root = ({ store }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store} i18n={i18n} >
            <Router history={browserHistory} >
                <Route name="app" path='/' component={App} />
                <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
};

Root.propTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Root;
```

Here's the login component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actionCreators from './action-creators';
import Login from './comp-login';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login">
                <Login />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log('ownProps', ownProps); // not getting i18n as props
    return { loginState: state.Login, ownProps };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);

const LoginPage = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(LoginForm);

export default LoginPage;
```

How can I access the i18n in provider's props, and even the login component can access it?

thanks for enlightening me =)

Comment: Have you looked at [`react-intl`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)

Comment: I did, and that is a wonderful tool. However, that's not my main questions. Even if I do decide to switch to react-intl, I still would like to know how to access provider's props. thanks for the suggestions!